# How to apply a custom formula over a group element in a grouped.apply().unstack() method?

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I'm using a version of this recipe in 'Python for Data analysis' p.269

```
frame = DataFrame({'data1': np.random.randn(1000),
                   'data2': np.random.randn(1000)})
factor = pd.cut(frame.data1, 4)
def get_stats(group):
   return {'min': group.min(), 'max': group.max(),
           'count': group.count(), 'mean': group.mean()}
grouped = frame.data2.groupby(factor)
grouped.apply(get_stats).unstack()

Out[101]:
                count      max      mean       min
data1
(-1.23, 0.489]    598 3.260383 -0.002051 -2.989741
(-2.956, -1.23]    95 1.670835 -0.039521 -3.399312
(0.489, 2.208]    297 2.954439  0.081822 -3.745356
(2.208, 3.928]     10 1.765640  0.024750 -1.929776
```

In the part where the formula get_stats(group) gets defined I want to include a function that counts the number of positive observations and divides them by the total number of observations. So I tried

```
def get_stats(group):
    return {'mean': group.mean(), 'std': group.std(),
            'hit_r': group.applymap(lambda x: x >= 0).sum() / group.count()}
```

However I got:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'
```

How can I find a way to incorporate that calculation over a group?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like when you group the dataframe it returns a bunch of series due to your original only having two columns.  `applymap` is a Dataframe method that applies a method element wise.  It looks like you are looking for apply in this instance.  Try the following...

```
def get_stats(group):
    return {'mean': group.mean(), 'std': group.std(),
            'hit_r': group.apply(lambda x: x >= 0).sum() / float(group.count())}
```

I also casted group.count() as a float that way the interpreter will realize it needs to do float division and not integer division